# Apache Running Processes

Tags: apache-2.2, process

Ok I host a website through a VPS with 1&1 and I'm worried about running out of processes.

From Parallels they have set a hard limit of 128 numprocs I have had some problems with my website just completely stopping and throwing me an error when I hit that limit.  Right now I'm at 52 numprocs (not bad).

**Does Apache create a new process every time someone views my site?**

**So if I got 200 people viewing my site I would have 200 processes (causing the site to take a dump)?**

**If so is there a way around this?**

BTW I've tried to get 1&1 to up the value but they insist I need to upgrade packages but this is dumb as can be because I am barely cracking my RAM, CPU and storage space. It is this stupid little parameter that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache creates one child process per request to maintain a certain configurable number of servers. Its not difficult to configure, but it is a little confusing.

Take a look at: http://virtualthreads.blogspot.com/2006/01/tuning-apache-part-1.html

Also, nginx is excellent for a VPS, its very lightweight and powerful. I would recommend it.

Comment: Keep in mind - this technique will not let you circumvent the 200 process limit.

Comment: I understand, it will at least give me some wiggle room though.

Answer (score 1):

First, your technical questions:

> So my question is...Does Apache create a new process every time
>   someone views my site?

No, it keeps a set number of servers ready to accept new connections, and typically it has a high bound set on how many of these servers it can spawn at a time. Each of these servers is configured with a max number of requests it can serve before it kills itself.

These items are configured in the MPM configuration section of your apache config.

> So if I got 200 people viewing my site I would have 200 processes
>   (causing the site to take a dump)?

200 concurrent requests? Yes, in that situation (and if apache is configured to allow this many connections), apache will try and spin up workers to service each of the 200 requests and you'll run into problems.

> If so is there a way around this?

No.

Now, onto the issues you're having with their service:

The reason that your provider is limiting your number of processes is that their "VPS" service doesn't provide a real, actual VPS. The service they provide is more like BSD-style jails. In this situation, all guests on a specific host share a single kernel. It is for this reason that they need to limit the number of processes each guest can spin up - the host's kernel needs to keep track of all of the processes for each guest, and limits are put in place to prevent one guest instance from negatively affecting others' ability to spawn new processes.

> I've tried to get 1&1 to up the value but they insist I need to
>   upgrade packages but this is dumb

Their limits are reasonable for the service they're providing. If you don't like it, then move somewhere else, to a *real* VPS provider - one that gives you your own OS instance. I use Linode and like them very much, but there are a ton of other options as well.

Comment: The way they walked around this issue did give me the feeling that it wasn't a true VPS.  I just figured they had some limitation that didn't need to be there.  I will be moving hosts, I was just hoping not to have to go through that hassle.  It seems really deceptive a VPS with nice specs but you hit a limit and it crashes on you. Thanks for the information extremely helpful!

Comment: Yes, **I** wouldn't call it a true VPS, but unfortunately there is precedent in the market for providers to call these Virtuozzo-based systems VPSes. So users just really need to do their own homework when choosing a vendor.

Comment: Answer edited to include the three technical questions.

Comment: It would seem as if security would be more of an issue on these systems as opposed to a true VPS being the kernel is shared.